# c++ regex: how to use sub-matches

Tags: c++, regex

This code will output `192.168.1.105` but I want it to find each number-part of the ip. The output would be

```
192
168
1
105
```

Since the `ip_result` only has 1 sub-match (`192.168.1.1`), how would I get 4 submatches for each number-part?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>
#include <string>

std::regex ip_reg("\\d{1,3}."
                  "\\d{1,3}."
                  "\\d{1,3}."
                  "\\d{1,3}");

void print_results(const std::string& ip) {
    std::smatch ip_result;
    if (std::regex_match(ip, ip_result, ip_reg))
        for (auto pattern : ip_result)
            std::cout << pattern << std::endl;
    else
        std::cout << "No match!" << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    const std::string ip_str("192.168.1.105");
    ip::print_results(ip_str);
}
```

Comment: Did you read the documentation? [This one](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_match) literally has a ready-made, annotated code example of what you're trying to do.

Comment: I didn't make it to that page yet...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I rewrote `ip_reg` to use sub-patterns and `print_results` to use iterators

```
std::regex ip_reg("(\\d{1,3})\\."
                  "(\\d{1,3})\\."
                  "(\\d{1,3})\\."
                  "(\\d{1,3})");

void print_results(const std::string& ip) {
    std::smatch ip_result;
    if (std::regex_match(ip, ip_result, ip_reg)) {
        std::smatch::iterator ip_it = ip_result.begin();
        for (std::advance(ip_it, 1);
             ip_it != ip_result.end();
             advance(ip_it, 1))
            std::cout << *ip_it << std::endl;
    } else
        std::cout << "No match!" << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: A  dot in a regex pattern matches any character but a linebreak char. To match a literal dot, a `.` must be escaped.

Answer (score 0):

If you replace `std::regex_match` with `std::regex_search`, loop that and always remove the match, you can access all the submatches. Also, you need to change the expression to only *one* group of digits:

```
 std::regex ip_reg{ "\\d{1,3}" };

void print_results(const std::string& ip_str) {
    std::string ip = ip_str; //make a copy!
    std::smatch ip_result;

    while (std::regex_search(ip, ip_result, ip_reg)){ //loop

        std::cout << ip_result[0] << std::endl;

        ip = ip_result.suffix(); //remove "192", then "168" ...
    }
}
```

output:

```
192
168
1
105
```

Comment: I like it but I wanted to keep the original regex

Comment: Makes sense. Good luck.